# Find derivative of tricky logarithmic functions

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Find the derivative of $y=(x^{x+1})(x+1)^x$

So this is what I have,

$$\ln y=\ln[(x^{x+1})(x+1)^x]$$

$$= \ln x^{x+1} + \ln(x+1)^x$$

$$\frac{1}{y}y' = (1)(\ln x) + (x+1)\frac{1}{x} + (1)(\ln(x+1)) + (x)\frac{1}{x+1}$$

$$= \ln x + \frac{x+1}{x} + \ln(x+1) + \frac{x}{x+1}$$

$$y' = (x^{x+1})(x+1)^x \left[\ln x + \ln(x+1) + \frac{x+1}{x} + \frac{x}{x+1}\right]$$

Is that the right answer?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Maybe if they want detail you should say explicitly that for example $\ln(x^{x+1})=(x+1)\ln x$.

Comment: Yes, it's right :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is the right answer..